# How can I use 'useQuery' as a callback function for a click event in React?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, react-hooks, event-handling

Please understand that I am not fluent in English.

How can I use 'useQuery' as a callback function for a click event in React?

The error contents are as follows.
'Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.'

```
const createGuestBookWrite = () => {
  const { data, error } = useQuery(GuestApi.ACTIONS.CREATE_GUEST_BOOK, async () => {
    return await GuestApi.fetchGuestBookWrite({
      spaceUid: 2,
      bookText: content,
    });
  });

  console.log('data::::::::::', data);
};


<span onClick={createGuestBookWrite}>
  <TextButton textID={I18N_CODE.GUESTBOOK_NEW_PUBLICATION}></TextButton>
</span>
```

Comment: As the error says a hook isn't supposed to be called like that. You should use the hook inside a component not a function that you call in an onclick.

If you need make a query based on an event, you should probably do that directly by calling `GuestApi.fetchGuestBookWrite`.

Comment: Also it could be helpfull to know where does the `useQuery` hook comes from